# Converting time to UTC time goes the opposite way

Tags: java, scala, datetime-format

I'm trying to parse an offset time using Java 8 DateTimeFormatter.

I live in EST time which is UTC-5, so when I try to convert

2019-01-22T13:09:54.620-05:00 should be --> 2019-01-22T18:09:54.620

However, with my code, it gets the current time and goes back 5 hours, resulting in 2019-01-22 08:09:54.620

Code:

```
import java.sql.Timestamp
import java.time._
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter

import scala.util.{Failure, Success, Try}

class MyTimeFormatter(parser: DateTimeFormatter) {

   def parse(input: String): Try[Timestamp] = {
    Try(new Timestamp(Instant.from(parser.withZone(ZoneOffset.UTC).parse(input)).toEpochMilli))
  }
}
```

Test:

```
new MyTimeFormatter(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSxxx")).parse("2019-01-22T13:09:54.620-05:00") shouldEqual Timestamp.valueOf("2019-01-22T18:09:54.620")
```

where parser is of type `DateTimeFormatter` and input string is just `"2019-01-22T13:09:54.620-05:00"`

I want to use this `parser.parse` method and not with specific temporalAccessors like `OffsetDateTime.parse(input, parser)` so I can handle all cases like `LocalTime, LocalDateTime, ZonedDateTime, OffsetDateTime, etc..`

It seems like the code just grabs the time, subtracts the offset, and brands it as UTC instead of calculating the offset with respect to UTC.

Also, is there a way to apply this UTC conversion only if the input format is of ZonedDateTime/OffsetDateTime format? If I input a LocalDateTime (which doesn't have an offset) such as `2017-01-01 12:45:00` the parser will still apply the UTC offset conversion because I told the parser to parse with zone UTC.

Comment: A complete working example is more likely to get an answer.

Comment: @TravisBrown added an example

Comment: Similar Question: [*Java Date and MySQL timestamp time-zones*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54330994/642706)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## tl;dr

Use modern *java.time* classes. Convert to legacy class only if necessary to work with old code.

Specifically, parse your input string as a `OffsetDateTime` object, adjust to UTC by extracting an `Instant`, and lastly, convert to `java.sql.Timestamp` (only if you must).

```
java.sql.Timestamp ts =                           // Avoid using this badly-designed legacy class if at all possible.
    Timestamp                                     // You can convert back-and-forth between legacy and modern classes.
    .from(                                        // New method added to legacy class to convert from modern class.
        OffsetDateTime                            // Represents a moment with an offset-of-UTC, a number of some hours-minutes-seconds ahead or behind UTC.
       .parse( "2019-01-22T13:09:54.620-05:00" )  // Text in standard ISO 8601 format can be parsed by default, without a formatting pattern.
       .toInstant()                               // Adjust from an offset to UTC (an offset of zero) by extracting an `Instant`. 
    )                                             // Returns a `Timestamp` object. Same moment as both the `OffsetDateTime` and `Instant` objects.
;
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/AS76bt), resulting in:

> ts.toString(): 2019-01-22 18:09:54.62

If using JDBC 4.2 or later, skip the `Timestamp` altogether.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , myOffsetDateTime ) ;
```

## Zulu

> 2019-01-22T13:09:54.620-05:00 should be --> 2019-01-22T18:09:54.620

If you meant that second value to represent a moment in UTC, append the offset-from-UTC to indicate that fact. Either `+00:00` or `Z` (pronounced “Zulu”): `2019-01-22T18:09:54.620Z`.

Reporting a moment without an offset-from-UTC or time zone indicator is like reporting an amount of money without a currency indicator.

## `OffsetDateTime`

A string with an offset-from-UTC should be parsed as a `OffsetDateTime` object.

Your input string happens to comply with the ISO 8601 standard formats for textual date-time values. The *java.time* classes use ISO 8601 formats by default when parsing/generating strings. So no need to specify a formatting pattern.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse( "2019-01-22T13:09:54.620-05:00" ) ;
```

## `Timestamp`

Apparently you want a `java.sql.Timestamp` object. This is one of the terrible date-time classes bundled with the earliest versions of Java. These classes are now legacy, supplanted entirely by the modern *java.time* classes with the adoption of JSR 310. Avoid these legacy classes whenever possible.

If you must have a `Timestamp` to interoperate with old code not yet updated to work with *java.time*, you can convert. To convert, call new methods added to the *old* classes.

## `Instant`

The [`java.sql.Timestamp`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Timestamp.html) class carries a [`from( Instant )`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Timestamp.html#from(java.time.Instant)) method. An `Instant` is a moment in UTC. To adjust from the offset of our `OffsetDateTime` to UTC, just extract an `Instant`.

```
Instant instant = odt.toInstant() ;
java.sql.Timestamp ts = Timestamp.from( instant ) ;
```

We have three objects ( `odt`, `instant`, & `ts` ) that all represent the same moment. The first has a different wall-clock time. But all three are the same simultaneous point on the timeline.

## JDBC 4.2

As of JDBC 4.2, we can directly exchange *java.time* objects with the database. So **no need to use `Timestamp`**.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , odt ) ;
```

…and…

```
OffsetDateTime odt = myResultSet.getObject( … , OffsetDateTime.class ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

While I cannot reproduce your issue precisely (even with changing my clock to EST), this is what I am observing:

```
Instant instant = Instant.from(parser.withZone(ZoneOffset.UTC).parse("2019-01-22T13:09:54.620-05:00"));
```

This is producing the time you would expect (2019-01-22T18:09:54.620Z).

```
Timestamp ts = new Timestamp(instant.toEpochMilli());
```

Because this is based on `java.util.Date`, which displays as your local time.

A better way to convert an `Instant` to a `Timestamp` is via the `LocalDateTime`, like so:

```
Timestamp ts = Timestamp.valueOf(instant.atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC).toLocalDateTime());
```

Comment: LocalDateTime works! This seems like an unfortunate problem as it looks like Timestamp isn't that compatible with Java 8 time, but I need to use Timestamp as I'm working with databases. Would you also happen to know if I could only apply this UTC conversion if ```input``` contains an offset? I asked this in the last paragraph of my question

Comment: I'm not clear what you're asking with that, but as a general rule on this site, please limit each question to a single question.  You may wish to raise this second item as a separate question.

Comment: Incorrect. A `LocalDateTime` lacks any concept of time zone or offset-from-UTC. So, by definition, it cannot represent a moment. A `LocalDateTime` is *not* a point on the timeline. A `LocalDateTime` represents *potential* moments along a range of about 26-27 hours (the range of time zones around the globe). `LocalDateTime` is exactly the class you should *not* be using here.

Comment: @BasilBourque Same goes with a `Timestamp`.

Comment: No, a `java.sql.Timestamp` represents a moment, a specific point on the timeline. Unfortunately, its poorly-designed `toString` method fails to mention an offset-from-UTC or time zone. But nevertheless, it has one, unlike `LocalDateTime`.