# Java Date and MySQL timestamp time-zones

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, timestamp

I'm editing a piece of code which basically does:

```
timestamp = new Date();
```

And then persist that `timestamp` variable in a `TIMESTAMP` MySQL table column.
However, while via debug I see the `Date` object displayed in the correct time-zone, **GMT+1**, when persisted on database it is a **GMT** time-zone, so an hour back.

Using the function `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` returns a GMT+1 date.
The connection string is `jdbc:mysql://..../db-name`, without any parameter.

**EDIT**:
Found this piece of code

```
preparedStatement.setTimestamp(2, new Timestamp(timestamp.getTime()));
```

What's happening?

Comment: You may want to use the MySQL `DATETIME` type, which is closer to the SQL standard `TIMESTAMP` than a MySQL `TIMESTAMP` type. The MySQL `TIMESTAMP` by definition is in UTC, while `DATETIME` is timezoneless and by JDBC requirements will use the JVM default timezone for conversion (haven't checked this in MySQL thoroughly, hence comment, not answer).

Comment: It's been a while, but it's my understanding that MYSQL always converts timestamp values to "raw" utc for internal storage, but converts them back to the local time zone (as per your connection settings) when you run a query.  If you run a SELECT from the database (as opposed to just viewing the data in a grid), are you still seeing UTC, or do you get back utc+1?

Comment: @markaaronky I still see GMT timestamps

Comment: @MarkRotteveel which `PreparedStatement` method should I use with a `DATETIME` column?

Comment: `setTimestamp`. As I said, a MySQL `DATETIME` is closer to the SQL standard `TIMESTAMP` (and JDBC defers to the SQL standard for things like datatypes).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Nada, tried but still the same result. I have really no idea

Comment: re#what's happening: it's a "short hand" conversion of `java.util.Date` into `java.sql.Timestamp` (via the "milliseconds since sine 1/1/1970") ..and `Date`is always **local** TZ  based.

Comment: @xerx593 what's the better why to handle this?

Comment: db column is `TIMESTAMP`...

Comment: ..see this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18615191/592355

Comment: What happens if you set connection property `useLegacyDatetimeCode=false`?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel same result. The program uses this timestamp to check elapsed time, so being one hour back is a problem

Comment: but my link approves `preparedStatement.setTimestamp` ...it's in the mismatch of your db tz setting and your "jvm tz" settings ...

Comment: [this guy says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36793896/592355): "just add `?serverTimezone=UTC` to url string". of course all of the article/question is interesting/ & realted.

Comment: ...mysqlDoc has a [whole chapter "Time Zone Support"](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/time-zone-support.html) ;(;(

Comment: ..but in any case, you should know: what your "jvm tz" is, what your "db tz" is (maybe control them to your needs) ...and consider that java works internally with "local time" (since 1/1/1970:)

Comment: @xerx593 JVM default timestamp is set to "Europe/Rome"

Comment: ..then "try": `jdbc:mysql://..../db-name?serverTimezone=CET`, but what to do, when "summer comes"... maybe this can help/is worth research: `&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true` [see: older mysql version, same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26515700/592355)

Comment: @xerx593 done everything, same result :(

Comment: Near duplicate of: [*Converting time to UTC time goes the opposite way*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54314299/642706)

Comment: @BasilBourque Thanks for the comprehensive answer! And thanks also to the other guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## tl;dr

```
myPreparedStatement
.setObject(  
    … ,                                   // Specify which placeholder `?` in your SQL statement. 
    OffsetDateTime.now( ZoneOffset.UTC )  // Capture the current moment as seen in the wall-clock time of UTC (an offset-from-UTC of zero).
) ;
```

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

You are using terrible date-time classes that were supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes.

Never use `Date` or `Timestamp`.

## UTC

Capture the current moment, in UTC. Most databases store a moment in UTC. And generally you should do most of your business logic, debugging, logging, storage, and data exchange in UTC.

## `OffsetDateTime`

Represent a moment with an offset-from-UTC using the aptly named `OffsetDateTime` class.

We want UTC itself, or an offset of zero. We can use a constant for that, `ZoneOffset.UTC`.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.now( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ) ;
```

## JDBC 4.2

As of JDBC 4.2 we can directly exchange *java.time* objects with the database.

To save this moment to a column of a data type akin to the SQL-standard `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`:

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , odt ) ;
```

Retrieval:

```
OffsetDateTime odt = myResultSet.getObject( … , OffsetDateTime.class ) ;
```

## `ZonedDateTime`

To present this retrieved moment to the user, you may want to adjust into the user’s expected/desired time zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = odt.atZoneSameInstant( z ) ;
```

## Never rely on default time zone

Notice in the code above that we always specified the desired/expected offset or zone.

If you do not specify, an offset or zone is silently implicitly applied. Better to specify your intentions explicitly as the current default of your JVM, database, and host OS are all out of your hands as a programmer. Which means code relying on the default will vary in behavior at runtime.

## Java 6 & 7

> However I'm still forced to deal with Java 6

The same man, Stephen Colebourne, who leads JSR 310 and the *java.time* implementation, as well as the famous *Joda-Time* project, also leads another project, [*ThreeTen-Backport*](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/). Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in this library, with nearly identical API.

So do all your work in back-port classes. Then, at the last moment, convert to/from `java.sql.Timestamp` via the [`DateTimeUtils`](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/apidocs/org/threeten/bp/DateTimeUtils.html) class.

Those conversion methods mostly use `Instant` objects. An `Instant` is a moment in UTC, always in UTC. You can adjust from your `OffsetDateTime` to UTC by extracting an `Instant`. The `Instant` class is the basic building-block class in *java.time*, with `OffsetDateDate` having more flexibility such as alternate formatting patterns when generating a string. But both `Instant` and `OffsetDateTime` represent a moment, a point on the timeline.

```
Instant instant = odt.toInstant() ;  
java.sql.Timestamp ts = org.threeten.bp.DateTimeUtils.toSqlTimestamp( instant ) ;
```

Going the other direction, retrieving a `Timestamp` from your database, then immediately converting to a `Instant`.

```
java.sql.Timestamp ts = myResultSet.getTimestamp( … ) ;
Instant instant = org.threeten.bp.DateTimeUtils.toInstant( ts ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: Hi Basil, gonna read everything when I get home. However I'm still forced to deal with Java 6, so...

Comment: @LppEdd Most of the *java.time* functionality with virtually identical API is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in the *ThreeTen-Backport* project. For JDBC, convert to/from `Timestamp` using the utils class in that library.

Comment: @LppEdd When restricted to an end-of-life’d version, you should note that fact on your Question.